# Can maven profiles be used for migrating applications from one technology stack to another?

Tags: java, migration, maven-3, maven-profiles

I have a few applications that needs to be migrated from one technology stack to another.

Please refer below for sample dependencies:

Example:

***Stack 1:***

d1-stack1,
d2-stack1,
Java 7,
Apache CXF,
Spring 3,
.....
..
etc.

***Stack 2:***

d1-stack2,
d2-stack2,
Java 8,
RESTEasy,
Spring 4,
.....
..
etc.

Here, d1-stack1, d2-stack1 etc. are maven projects that are used in these applications as dependencies and these dependencies also needs to be migrated to new stack.

In order to migrate all the applications and their dependencies smoothly, I am thinking of abstracting out the applications' dependencies behind common interfaces (Facade, Adopter etc.) and then I am thinking of using maven profiles (stack-1 and stack-2) for adding the dependencies for respective technology stacks for build.

Do you think this approach will be helpful in long term? Will there be any blockers?

Please note dependencies like d1-stack* and d2-stack* will have different framework dependencies for both stacks.

Comment: Although you reason well, and I think you will get a long way, there will be problems in the application as it is will become unlikely that the code will match both platforms really good.

One simple example is using Java7 vs Java8 language syntax in the source code. It will then depend on the profile to succeed.